# Why getting the different results strsplit function

Tags: r

```
s = "hi@hello"
strsplit(s,"@")[[1]]
```

my output result is  ***"hi"    "hello"***

but i got the different result when using the "*" symbol.

```
s = "hi*hello"
strsplit(s,"*")[[1]]
```

output result is ***"h" "i" "*" "h" "e" "l" "l" "o"***

May i know the strsplit function working different on the * and + symbol.

Comment: Because `*` is a meta-character in regex. You need to escape it in order to use it literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `fixed = TRUE` as it is a metacharacter signifying zero or more characters.  THe solution is to add `fixed = TRUE` or escape (`\\*`)

```
strsplit(s,"*", fixed= TRUE)[[1]]
```